# Does it make sense to use clustered standard errors outside of a regression framework?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, clustered-standard-errors

I am unsure about how to proceed in the following context. Here is some toy data from R:

```
 location value
     <chr> <dbl>
1      A     0  
2      A     2  
3      A     1  
4      B     2  
5      B     3  
6      B     0.4
```

I would like to do t-tests on `value`. In my mind, it would make sense to consider clustering standard errors by `location` if I were to use these variables in a regression.

Is it possible considering that instead I only want to do means testing on `value`?

I ask because in R all packages that consider such cluster robust calculations only work when evaluating regression estimates.

Comment: Why not do the regression version of a t-test?

Comment: But I actually dont see which regression should I be using

Comment: Regress value on location (treated as a factor), clustering the SEs on location. You will need more than two locations for the clustering to work well.

Comment: In such case I still have the interpretation as a test for the mean?

Comment: Yes. Regression models the conditional mean. For example, if A was the omitted category, the intercept would give you the mean of value for A. The coefficient would give you the difference between B and A.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov now I have noticed that I have not been clear enough. I don't want to calculate a conditional mean. I want to make a test on the unconditional mean, but considering the fact that observations within the same location are arbitrarilly correlated. Does that make any sense?

Comment: This is precisely what the regression coefficients and their SEs allow you to do. You can the perform hypothesis tests on them.

Comment: The mean here is conditional because it depends on location. If you just want to test that the overall mean is equal to some number, that is also possible.

Comment: Is that possible while still considering clustering? In such case, what would be the adequate regression?

Comment: The latter example is just a regression on a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing the regression analog of a difference in means test, or independent samples $t$-test, will give you the standard error of that difference with no extra work on your part. One crucial assumption is that the observations are *independent*. In your example, each value is not a realization from a new location; rather, you have multiple realizations for the *same location*. It is important to think about *how* your sample was collected when clustering.

You most likely have a sample of observations (locations) from *within* the same geographic region, or you have repeated observations of locations *across time*. Dimitriy correctly noted that your difference in means test is mathematically equivalent (assuming equal variances) to the following

$$
\mathrm{Value}_{it} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\mathrm{Location}_{it},
$$

which is the outcome regressed on a two-level factor variable. I use the subscripts $i$ and $t$ which is characteristic of a panel setup. For example, observing values for location $i$ repeated over some time interval $t$. Clustering on location is easier under this framework. Be mindful, clustering on location with few clusters is not recommended. Cluster robust variance estimation can be biased downward with too few clusters. See the following paper by [Pustyjovsky and Tipton 2018](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07350015.2016.1247004?scroll=top&needAccess=true) for more information.

The regression formulation is useful. You can cluster. You can add more locations (40 or more clusters is preferred). You can even condition on other covariates. And lastly, you will not have to calculate the standard errors; R will do it for free.

If you only care about the overall mean, then run an intercept-only model. To be precise, set $\beta_{0} = 1$. Next, simply cluster on your location variable. I hope that helps!

Comment: What I dont get is that in my mind I would obtain only one t-statistic alongside one Standard error since what I want is to test the unconditional mean. However, by doing as suggested, since I have 400 clusters, I would actually get 400 coefficients.

Comment: To be clear, you have 400 locations. And you have multiple observations on each of these locations. Do you want to test for differences *between* the locations (because you are conditioning on location) while also account for within-cluster dependence?

Comment: No. It is more simple than that. I only want to test if values are unconditionally diferente from 0, accounting for within-cluster dependence

Comment: The model now becomes: $\mathrm{Value}_{it} = 1$. Then, you can cluster on location using any one of R's numerous packages. Try `coeftest()` from the sandwich package: `coeftest(linear.model, vcov. = ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Stata example of testing a hypothesis about the overall mean log wage using a t-test (unadjusted for clustering) and a regression clustered at the individual level (since we have repeated wage observations for these women):

```
. webuse regsmpl, clear 
(NLS Women 14-26 in 1968)

. ttest ln_wage = 1.681

One-sample t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. Err.   Std. Dev.   [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 ln_wage |  28,534    1.674907    .0028303    .4780935     1.66936    1.680455
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mean = mean(ln_wage)                                          t =  -2.1527
Ho: mean = 1.681                                 degrees of freedom =    28533

  Ha: mean < 1.681             Ha: mean != 1.681             Ha: mean > 1.681
 Pr(T < t) = 0.0157         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0313          Pr(T > t) = 0.9843

. reg ln_wage , cluster(idcode )

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =     28,534
                                                F(0, 4710)        =       0.00
                                                Prob > F          =          .
                                                R-squared         =     0.0000
                                                Root MSE          =     .47809

                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 4,711 clusters in idcode)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
     ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   1.674907   .0061246   273.47   0.000       1.6629    1.686914
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test _cons = 1.681

 ( 1)  _cons = 1.681

       F(  1,  4710) =    0.99
            Prob > F =    0.3199
```

As you can see the clustered SE of the mean from the regression (.0061246) is much bigger than in the t-test (.0028303), and so we fail to reject the null when clustering (p-value of 0.32), but reject it when not clustering (p-value is 0.03). This makes sense, since you expect that wage observations for a given woman are positively correlated over time. Pretending that you have 28,534 independent observations instead of 4,711 women observed repeatedly ~6 times on average would deflate your standard errors since the panel data contains a lot less information.